# When using Express.js, why does Google Chrome ignore my Content-Disposition?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, header

My code (in Express.js) is as follows:

```
res.header("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + "\"DUMMYNAME.pdf\"");
```

In Chrome Developer Tools the header appears as follows:

[image]

But the actual PDF renders like this:

[image]

Why does Chrome ignore my file name (by using 5b45bb58361d366bf10b5bad as the file name instead of DUMMYNAME.pdf)?

Comment: Huh. The [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266#section-4.3) says that should be fine (even for `inline`), although every example I've ever seen has a space after the `;`. So maybe give that a try...? (And of course, remember the filename is only advisory, Chrome can ignore it if it wants to.)

Comment: *"Why does Chrome ignore my file name (by using 5b45bb58361d366bf10b5bad as the file name instead of DUMMYNAME.pdf)?"* When do you see this?

Comment: Just double-checking: It's your intent that the PDF should be shown in the browser, right? That's what `inline` means. If you want Chrome to (fairly) reliably offer a "Save as" dialog with that filename, you'd want `attachment`, not `inline`. But I assume you're doing that on purpose, and expecting the filename to be used if the user tries to save the PDF later from within Chrome.

Comment: Confirming that I want the inline behaviour. Even with the space, I'm still getting the wrong file name displaying.

Comment: Okay, great. Where, specifically, are you seeing this filename? What action are you taking that shows it to you? Do you have **any** extensions installed? What is your setting for `chrome://settings/content/pdfDocuments?search=pdf`?

Comment: TJ, thanks for your reply. I'm seeing the file name in the top left of the viewer (to the left of the page count, which is in the middle). To see that file, I'm accessing an API in my app which sends the PDF back to the browser. I have an extension called Grammarly installed. My setting is to NOT download PDF files instead of opening them in Chrome.

Comment: Okay. Best to put all that information in the question (via the "edit" link). Good luck with this!

Comment: I guess Chrome displays 5b45bb58361d366bf10b5bad because it is the name stored in the PDF's metadata. The program that build the PDF should set proper metadata to be displayed in various PDF viewer (including chrome's).

Comment: @Hoa did you figure this out by any chance?